# looking for a hosting company for wordpress

Tags: domain, hosting

I've never purchased hosting space from any company before. I have looked around and I saw that some of these companies claim that they specialise in wordpress hostings. Initially I thought I'd just purchase a normal hosting page, maybe their most basic package as I won't be expecting many visitors. Maybe under 10k visits per month with at least 10GB of space.

Also, what's the difference between a normal hosting space vs a specialised one for wordpress. If I'm using wordpress as a CMS, must I absolutely choose a specialised wordpress host?

Currenty, my wordpress website is being developed on my localhost and nearly done. How would I go about transfering that website to the hosting space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WordPress is extremely lenient to the hosting requirements. It is likely one of the most forgiving CMSes to run on the least capable PHP hosts.

That said there *are* advantages to *some* of hosts that specialize in WP. Those that *do* specialize and not just slap it on as marketing gimmick.

I would put advantages in roughly two categories:

1. Expertise. Specialized hosts have better awareness of WP as a solution, what it takes to run it smoothly, and keep it secure.
2. Tooling. Specialized hosts can offer server configuration and features specifically fine–tuned for WordPress, such as object cache backend or reverse proxy.

So while specialized hosts is completely unnecessary, there are some concrete benefits that make sense if budget works out for it.

Personally I highly value reverse proxy feature, since it removes the need for flaky static page cache plugins.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. Does that mean if I take a basic host space I won't have access to wpadmin?

Comment: Everything will work just fine as long as host satisfies basic system requirement of WordPress. Of course with cheap hosts you generally get what you pay for.

Answer (score 0):

You should get a hosting provider since it's part of their service to make sure your websites are all up 99% of the time. I have a good experience with iPage and I can help you set that up.